# checksum fields in the socket buffer

Tags: network-programming, checksum

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `csum_start` and `csum_offset` fields in `struct sk_buff`.

Googling for them, I came across the following definition:

`csum_start` is the offset from the address of `skb->head` to the address of the checksum field.
`csum_offset` is the offset from the beginning of the address of checksum to the end.

1. When are these fields actually used?
2. If the checksum is offloaded to a device driver via `NETIF_F_HW_CSUM`, how are the aforementioned values to be used/interpreted in this context?

Any insight on the above is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a device's feature is set to `NETIF_F_HW_CSUM`, then the network stack does not compute the transport checksum on the transmit path. Instead, it tells the device to compute the checksum by setting `ip_summed` to `CHECKSUM_PARTIAL`.

The device shall use `csum_start` (or `skb_checksum_start_offset(skb)` occasionally) as the starting position and compute the checksum till the end of the packet (`len` field in socket buffer). The computed checksum is stored at `csum_offset` from `csum_start`.